# Inserting ASM.JS code into vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, asm.js

Just a simple question, can I include a section of asm.js code in a set of normal javascript, as a function or otherwise, similar to how I can put ASM code into a C program for areas that need special optimization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use the

```
"use asm";
```

prologue directive on top of the function block (i.e. function or file) that is asm. Full example:

```
function MyAsmModule() {
    "use asm";
    // module body
}
```

See http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#introduction for more information

Comment: Could you show how to pass variables into a function like this, let's assume it was originally written in C++ and then compiled into ASM.

Comment: There's a good example in the link I posted. You should have a pretty good idea of the possibilities after reading the introduction part of that page.